# Problem running .exe from C# code

Tags: c#-4.0, imagemagick, shellexecute

I have this function which should run a shell command.
This is how I call this:

```
RunCommand("C:\\source\\in\\DSC00749.jpg -gravity Center -crop 100x100+0+0 -write C:\\source\\out\\DSC00749.jpg");

private static string RunCommand(string cmd)
    {
        const int ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND = 2;
        const int ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED = 5;

        string strErrMsg = "OK";

        try
        {
            ProcessStartInfo procInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("convert.exe");

            procInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            procInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

            procInfo.Arguments = cmd;
            Process.Start(procInfo);
        }
        catch (Win32Exception e)
        {
            if (e.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND)
            {
                strErrMsg = "File not found exception";
            }
            else if (e.NativeErrorCode == ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED)
            {
                strErrMsg = "Access Denied Exception";
            }
        }

        return strErrMsg;
    }
```

If I run this in command shell it works:

```
convert.exe C:\\source\\in\DSC00749.jpg -gravity Center -crop 100x100+0+0-write C:\\source\\out\\DSC00749.jpg
```

If I run in debug more or directly run it, it just doesn't create the images.

What is wrong with my code? Am I doing it the right way?

Comment: Have you tried to debug it by stepping in?  Also, how does this relate to asp.net and mvc3?

Comment: Are you trying to run this command from an asp.net-mvc app? Why did you flag it as asp.net? If it is an asp.net mvc app I would imagine that 1: Either the executable file is not in the same directory as where the app is being hosted and therefore it cannot run the command or 2: You need elevated permissions to run executable files from the asp.net account

Comment: I flagged MVC since this is mvc app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have full path to the convert.exe?

Try that and see if it works since you are not getting any exception.

Comment: Hmm.. I already had the env variable set. May be that only works in shell.

Answer (score 1):

<s>You're missing a backslash: `C:\\source\\in\\DSC00749.jpg`</s>

<s>To avoid further mistakes, prefix the string with `@` if it contains backslashes.  Example: `@"My Path\My Filename"`</s>

Moreover, you appear to be "swallowing" certain `Win32Exception`s by handling only certain kinds of that exception.  You should include `throw;` at the end of the catch block to rethrow `Win32Exception`s  you're not handling.  It might be a different Win32Exception that reports neither "File not found" nor "Access denied".

Comment: That was a typo. I changed the path for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind this is running asynchronously with your code, so the `Process.Start` call will return immediately. What happens if you call `WaitForExit()` afterwards?

Also I'm not sure why you tagged this with mvc-3 but if you're running this from a web app you need to make sure you have permissions to do so.

Comment: The code will be triggered by controller action. So this will run within web app.

Comment: +1 Precisely my thoughts. The user probably doesn't have permissions for the specified folders

Comment: Not the user, the account under which the IIS app (or the app pool) is running.

Comment: The app is on my laptop. So Network Services needs access to the folder? This might not be an issue. I see code is able to save uploaded files just fine.

Comment: kprobst. I was talking about the "user account" for the iis yes.. often just referred to as 'user"